# different versions of file downloads from different locations

Tags: caching, proxies

When I download a file using the same URL from my computer in Australia or from my VPS in Singapore, I get different versions of the same file. This seems to be a caching issue. Is there a way I can force my computer in Australia to use the same source for downloads as the VPS in Singapore to ensure I always get the latest version of a file as soon as it is posted by the author?

It turns out it is not a caching issue but I am not sure what tag to use to update this post: filesystem?

Cheers,
Gaetano.

Comment: it gets even more strange. When I open the archive with WinRAR or Winzip, the date shows as 12th Jan, when I open it with Windows Explorer it shows 22nd Jan. How can this be?? When I look at the properties of the file, it was created on 15th Jan but was last modified on 12th Jan - could this corruption in dates explain this oddity? but then, why can Windows Explorer show the right date while Winzip and WinRAR can't? I have never seen anything like this in 30 years of computer experience...

Answer (score 0):

It runs out that the file's last saved date was 12th Jan and the Document.created date was 23rd Jan. Windows sees a discrepancy and display 23rd Jan because a document cannot be saved prior to being created. WinRAR and WinZip both just take the lastSaved date to display the date of the file and apparently that date becomes the file's date upon unzipping them. The file was actually the right version all along, there was just conflicting info about it's timestamp due to some sort of corruption in the various date properties of the file.